# OS X open source photo library manager

Tags: open-source, osx, photography

I need an open source photo library manager for OS X, that doesn't create it's own library file (like Apple Photos do), and which

- is capable of
  adding tags
- is capable of
  visualizing photos on map
- can scan a directory recursively, perheaps even use compressed photos without decompression (not required)
- doesn't crash when fed with `10 GiB` of data (this was the issue of Dark Table)
- looks decent and is Mac-native
- supports basic picture tuning, like adjusting brightness and cropping

Comment: I'm guessing that https://www.digikam.org/ is out do to the "create it's own library file" and "Mac-native"